# php line break in result set

Tags: php, html, css

i want to create a fixed size for showing my result set i put my result set shownig inside a fixed size div but doesn't works

```
<div class ="para" >
    Brand:  <?php echo $row13[2]?></br>
    Model:  <?php echo $row13[3]?></br>
    Price:  <?php echo $row13[7]?></br>

    <?php echo $row13[4]?>                 
  <?php 
  }            
?>
```

I wont to show the description of fixed width size

[image]

Comment: Did you try to use css to style your layout? Post it if any.

Comment: yes `.para {
     margin-top:-220px;
 margin-left:930px;
 width:100px;
    }
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
    .para {
        margin-top:10px;
     margin-left:82px;
  
    }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a css rule to the .para class:

```
.{
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

you could also add `hyphens: auto;` to add the hypen that "cuts" the word

> Note: In contrast to word-break, overflow-wrap will only create a break if an entire word cannot be placed on its own line without overflowing.
>
> The property was originally a nonstandard and unprefixed Microsoft extension called word-wrap, and was implemented by most browsers with the same name. It has since been renamed to overflow-wrap, with word-wrap being an alias.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

Answer (score 0):

you can be use these css :-

```
style="position:absolute; overflow:auto; width:100px; min-height:100px;"
```

you could also use this:-

```
.class_name{
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```